# Is 2 EJBs calling each other bad practice?

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have the 2 following stateless EJBs that as you can see have a reference to the other one.

```
@Stateless
public class EjbA {

    @Inject
    private EjbB b;

}

@Stateless
public class EjbB {

    @Inject
    private EjbA a;

}
```

Is that a bad practice ? Can this cause a memory leak ?

**EDIT**

If one af the EJB is Stateful, is that the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a bad practice.

This is the recommended way of doing if you want to change the transactionnal context as you should know that calling a method inside an EJB is not catched by the container and thus transactionnal properties are not modified.

But be aware that this creates a new instance if an EJB X is injected in itself.

I don't know what happens with Statefull EJBs

Answer (score 0):

Think about the code without any EJB specific annotations:

```
public class EjbA {

    private EjbB b;
}

public class EjbB {

    private EjbA a;
}
```

Here you have circular dependencies between two classes. Generally it is a bad practice to keep in the code such relation. Marking both classes as EJBs you give them additional power (e.g. transactions, dependency injection, instance pool). However the problem with circular relation is still in place. In order to eliminate further potential problems try to avoid such design.

Answer (score 0):

that's only make sense if both EJB are @stateful: you have 2 different objects that related between they double visibility. If not it does not make sense because de @stateless will always reset the @stateful in each call or you can supply the @stateless method with a static method call.